# Can I configure localhost ports to be subdomains?

Tags: docker, server, debian, reverse-proxy, cdn

I have a debian based home-server running in my home network (port-forwarding is disabled due to security reasons). There are multiple services/web-applications running using docker based deployment. Is it possible to map different ports to subdomains for a hostname running in a home network?

For instance, currently I have configured my modem to provide static IP and hostname to my server and I access services using http://host-name.local:port_number. Is it possible to setup subdomains to access different applications like http://wiki.host-name.local and http://grafana.host-name.local?

Comment: yes, it is possible. But: you must be more precise. "services" are just http servers, right? In any case, I think your question if off-topic (Unix and Linux Stack Exchange is probably more relevant), but you will find a lot of answer in this site. The keyword is "reverse proxy" and very standard with dockers and in general using many web-applications.

Comment: You are right. Services can be generic too.. However, in this context the services mean web-applications running in the different docker containers on a same server. 

Good tip to post similar queries in Unix/Linux Stack exchange. I will take a note for the future posts.  Also, will be updating the original question.

Comment: On the server you need a reverse proxy, so a mini-webserver which ask different services (and so dockers domain/ports) the content and deliver it to users. Internet has just connections (so numbers), so it is HTTP which has the URL (as name), and so only HTTP programs can interpret it. A reverse proxy is just a small dispatcher.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the ideas. I have gone for a CDN provider, cloudflare.com, to act as a reverse proxy and add additional layer of security for DDoS mitigation. Of course, I have also enabled Multi-factor authentication for all my web applications before exposing them on the external network. Cheers!

Comment: If you add a bit more detail, it would be easier for someone solving the same problem could do so.